# Window Forms PDF Upload to Database using LINQ

Tags: winforms, linq

My team and I are working on an application using Window Form with LINQ. We need help to upload PDF and Word Document File to the Database using LINQ. Kindly assist with a code snippet on how to go about this using LINQ

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create an entity with a property of type `byte[]`.  Copy the file bytes to that property and save it in the database.